# npm scripts in package.json errors on exit

Tags: node.js, npm, jestjs, eslint

I'm able to run my scripts successfully, however, when i exit (ctrl + c) I get a loud error from the eslint, or jest jobs that were watching.  Is there a means of suppressing these, as I get errors from the package themselves when the tests or linting fails

Example error:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.5.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "lint"
npm ERR! node v7.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! wpauth@1.0.0 lint: `esw webpack.config.* src tools --color`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the wpauth@1.0.0 lint script 'esw webpack.config.* src tools --color'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the wpauth package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     esw webpack.config.* src tools --color
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs wpauth
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls wpauth
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/gazzwi86/Sites/tokenauth/npm-debug.log
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "wpauth",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run start:dev",
    "start:dev": "npm-run-all --parallel test:watch lint:watch serve:dev open:dev",
    "start:dist": "npm-run-all build open:dist serve:dist",
    "prebuild": "rm -r src/main/webapp/public/secure-me && mkdir src/main/webapp/public/secure-me && npm run test && npm run lint",
    "build": "webpack -p --define process.env.NODE_ENV='\"production\"' --optimize-minimize && cp ./src/ui/index.html src/main/webapp/public/secure-me/",
    "lint": "esw webpack.config.* src tools --color",
    "lint:watch": "npm run lint -- --watch",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "open:dev": "open http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/",
    "open:dist": "open http://localhost:8080/",
    "serve:dev": "webpack-dev-server --progress --colors --content-base src/ui",
    "serve:dist": "http-server src/main/webapp/public/secure-me"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
      "^.+\\.(gif|ttf|eot|svg|woff|woff2|ico)$": "<rootDir>/fileMock.js"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "backbone": "^1.3.3",
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-jest": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "enzyme": "^2.7.1",
    "eslint": "^3.15.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.9.0",
    "eslint-watch": "^2.1.14",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "jest-cli": "^18.1.0",
    "npm-run-all": "3.1.2",
    "open": "0.0.5",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.4.2",
    "sinon": "^1.17.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it happen when you run a script solely? (e.g. `lint:watch`)

Comment: @OrB it appears not.